# How to debug Intent in sub project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-intent

I have a eclipse workspace with 3 subprojects

- myMp3TagBusineslogic (lib that can be used for android and for j2se)
- myMp3TagActivity_*Plugin* (android activity that uses myMp3TagBusineslogic and that can be launched by MyFIles, OIFilemanager and other apps: A gui to edit/view mp3-tags )
- myMp3Tag_*Test*_Activity (some android activity used to test myMp3TagActivityPlugin by just executing `Intent mp3Tagger = ... ; startActivity(mp3Tagger);`

Reason for this layout: seperate guiplugin from testcode.

my qestion: how is it possible to debug the code of myMp3TagActivityPlugin by executing myMp3TagTestActivity?

What I tried so far:

- Set a breakpoint in onCreate of myMp3TagActivity_*Plugin* and started debugging myMp3Tag_*Test*_Activity

  - effect: debugger does not stop in myMp3TagActivity_*Plugin*. Plugin is executed correctly.
- Add plugin and myMp3TagBusineslogic to buildpath of myMp3Tag_*Test*_Activity

  - effect: cannot start myMp3Tag_*Test**Activity:  myMp3TagActivity**Plugin* class not found.

Edit: Update and solution for those who have the same problem:

- as the comment below states the buildpath that includes the plugin into the test was not complete and therefore the testactivity crashed. Correct **buildpath**

  - add projects plugin
  - add projects busines
  - order and exports check plugin (i forgot before)
  - order and exports check busines  (i forgot before)
- however after uninstalling the plugin.apk from the device and debugging the test.apk (that now really contains the plugin-code and a combined manifest)  the debugger still does not stop in the plugin-code.
- after adding `Debug.waitForDebugger()` to the plugin-source and debugging the test.apk i finally could debug the plugin source.

Comment: You mean intent, not intend, right?

Comment: yes i meant Intent. fixed typo in question

Comment: Your real problem here is the second thing you tried, it must be some trivial reason why it can't find that class and when it does the debugging should work

Comment: @whatsthebeef: if you make it an answer i can upvote it. This is not complete solution but an important part to solve the problem. See update to my qestion.

Comment: Don't usually answer in comments but got down voted last week for a similar sort of answer (although I think the down voter was wrong). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try below method, might well work.

Add a call `Debug.waitfordebugger()` in `myMp3TagActivity_Plugin` entry point. Execute `myMp3Tag_Test_Activity`. Now the activity will show waiting for debugger to connect.
 Then find the port  of the process `myMp3TagActivity_Plugin` , usually starts from 8600 as you can see below.

[image]

Then Right click myMp3TagActivity_Plugin project, debug as -> Debug Configurations -> Double click remote java app change port in connection properties to match above(8600) -> Debug.

Answer (score 2):

Your real problem here is the second thing you tried.

> Add plugin and myMp3TagBusineslogic to buildpath of
>   myMp3Tag_Test_Activity effect: cannot start myMp3Tag_TestActivity:
>   myMp3TagActivityPlugin class not found.

It must be some trivial reason why it can't find that class and when it does the debugging should work.

Comment: +1: this is of course not an answer to the question but an imporant part of the final solution. I asked @whatsthebeef to make it an answer so i can upvote it.